# How should I implement H2O.ai model in C#?

Tags: .net, machine-learning, h2o

I have built a model in H2O.ai however I would like to now use this model in C#/.net.

Answer (score 1):

There is a library on github which can convert a Java Pojo output from H2O.ai into dotnet.

https://github.com/cozmoash/h2o-ai-pojo-to-dotnet

Disclaimer - I am the owner of this library.

Answer (score 0):

There is a (not well known) C# MOJO shim library with an integrated C++ implementation that enterprise customers of H2O.ai can ask (their sales rep) about.